# Overriding a custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter causes both to be instantiated

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Here's my situation: I have a project that has is using Spring Security. All is working well.

I have this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler getAuthenticationFailureHandler(){
         return new PlainFailureHandler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSec) throws Exception {
        AuthFilter filter = new AuthFilter(getAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        httpSec.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);        
    }

}
```

And so far, everything is great. Now, I have a second project that is built on top of this first project.

In it, I need to override the AuthenticationFailureHandler.

I created a new class in my second project, and it looks similar:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class NewProjectSecurityConfig extends SecurityConfig {

    @Override
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler getAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new NewProjectAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }
}
```

And now my problem is that Spring is instantiating both of them, resulting in two filters. I can add an `@Order(1)` to make sure that one gets done before the other, but what I really want is *only* to use the second config, and somehow tell Spring to use it *instead* of the first. I'm still new with Spring, so I apologize if I've missed a 'bigger picture' item. I'm also unable to change Project 1, so I can't just remove the original config and duplicate it.

NOTE: I am not using config files at all, this is all done programatically.

Comment: did you solve this problem. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I did not. I ended up with a painful hack to remove the other filter afterwards using reflection.

Comment: I am able to disable parent configuration from instantiating by using @ConditionalOnProperty. but I am unable to inherit the parent config in subclass.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a limitation of the current way to setup config.
If you look at `WebSecurityConfiguration` class it has `setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer` method which has injection of all webSecurityConfigurers resolved by `AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents` class. It basically takes all beans that either extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` or implement `WebSecurityConfigurer`.

Now, that method will add all those configurers to `WebSecurity` object. It's `build` method then goes over all those configurers(in the methods like init()) and, basically, does the following for each configurer:

1. configurer.init()
2. configurer.configure()

Init method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is doing this:

```
public void init(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        final HttpSecurity http = getHttp();
        web.addSecurityFilterChainBuilder(http).postBuildAction(() -> {
            FilterSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = http
                    .getSharedObject(FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
            web.securityInterceptor(securityInterceptor);
        });
}
```

So, each of configurers will create and add its own filter chain.

In case your configurations are perfectly divided by using different urls, let's say one configurer is for "/api/v1" and another for "/api/v2" it may work.

However, if your configurations are kind of global or at least intersecting, you are in a big trouble.

Let's say one defines csrf.disable() and another has no csrf.disable().

Your web request will go through security chains, if it has no csrf token it will pass the first chain, but not the second. So, effectively instead of single configuration which is a mix of two(one overwrites/redefines the other)), you get configuration(two of them) which work as an **intersection** of two.

One of possible solutions is to extend existing configuration, call super() and redefine some configuration, but at the same time you need to make sure the original configuration is not in the beans list discovered by spring.